# get values from dict whose key values match another dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dicts whose values are themselves dicts.  I would like to create another dict whose values are the values from dict2 that have the same ‘asin’ key value as dict1.  I have example output below.  I haven’t worked with dicts that much so any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
dict1
    
{0:[{u’asin’: u’a’, u’h’: u’b’},{u’asin’: u’b’, u’h’: u’c’}], 1:[{u’asin’: u’c’, u’h’: u’b’},{u’asin’: u’d’, u’h’: u’c’}, 2:[{u’asin’: u’d’, u’h’: u’f’},{u’asin’: u’k’, u’h’: u’c’}]}
```

Code:

```
dict2
    
{0:{u’asin’: u’f’, u’img’: u’123’}, 1:{u’asin’: u’c’, u’img’: u’eed’}, 2:{u’asin’: u’d’, u’img’: u’ffg’}}
```

Desired Output:

```
{1:{u’asin’: u’c’, u’img’: u’eed’}, 2:{u’asin’: u’d’, u’img’: u’ffg’}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of comprehensions: a set comprehension to extract all keys from values of `d1`, and a dictionary comprehension to filter items in `d2`.

```
keys = {subdict['asin'] for item in d1.itervalues() for subdict in item}

d3 = {k: v for k, v in d2.iteritems() if v['asin'] in keys}

print(d3)

{1: {'asin': 'c', 'img': 'eed'}, 2: {'asin': 'd', 'img': 'ffg'}}
```

In Python 3.x, replace `itervalues` / `iteritems` with `values` / `items`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` to merge all sub-lists in `dict1` first before using list comprehension to filter `dict2`.

```
from itertools import chain
dict1 = {0:[{'asin': 'a', 'h': 'b'},{'asin': 'b', 'h': 'c'}], 1:[{'asin': 'c', 'h': 'b'},{'asin': 'd', 'h': 'c'}], 2:[{'asin': 'd', 'h': 'f'},{'asin': 'k', 'h': 'c'}]}
dict2 = {0:{'asin': 'f', 'img': '123'}, 1:{'asin': 'c', 'img': 'eed'}, 2:{'asin': 'd', 'img': 'ffg'}}
r = {d['asin'] for d in chain(*dict1.values())}
print({k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if v['asin'] in r})
```

This outputs:

```
{1: {'asin': 'c', 'img': 'eed'}, 2: {'asin': 'd', 'img': 'ffg'}}
```